# Object Equality in assertEquals

Tags: javascript, loops, tdd, equality

I am trying to compare 2 objects, first by if they have the same keys, then by if their key values are equal, yet the tests from assertEquals are still failing. I think it's because the two objects are inside of an array, so it's actually comparing one array of objects vs. another array of objects. Also, my actual object is made from a function whereas the expected object is a literal.

```
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function decorateClassListWithAges(classList) {
  return classList.reduce((arr, c) => {
    arr.push({
      'Name': c,
      'Age': getRandomIntInclusive(10, 10) //Currently always 10 for test purposes
    })
    return arr
  }, [])
}

function assertEquals(actual, expected, testName) {

  if (actual == null || typeof actual != 'object')
    return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));

  if (Object.keys(actual).length !== Object.keys(expected).length)
    return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));

     for (let k in actual)
       if (!expected.hasOwnProperty(k))
         return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));

         for (let k in expected) {
           if (actual[k] !== expected[k])
             return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));
         }
  return console.log('passed');
}


let a = ['James', 'Paul']
let e = [{'Name' : 'James', 'Age' : 10}, {'Name' : 'Paul', 'Age' : 10}]
assertEquals(decorateClassListWithAges(a), e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you try to compare two different objects:

```
for (let k in actual)
       if (!expected.hasOwnProperty(k))
         return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));

         for (let k in expected) {
           if (actual[k] !== expected[k])
             return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));
         }
```

But in JS two objects are equal if they refer to the exact same object.

You can compare this two objects using lodash `isEqual` method:

```
if (!_.isEqual(actual[k], expected[k]))...
```

Try snippet bellow:

```js
 function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    function decorateClassListWithAges(classList) {
      return classList.reduce((arr, c) => {
        arr.push({
          'Name': c,
          'Age': getRandomIntInclusive(10, 10) //Currently always 10 for test purposes
        })
        return arr
      }, [])
    }

    function assertEquals(actual, expected, testName) {

      if (actual == null || typeof actual != 'object')
        return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));

      if (Object.keys(actual).length !== Object.keys(expected).length)
        return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));

         for (let k in actual)
           if (!expected.hasOwnProperty(k))
             return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));

             for (let k in expected) {
               if (!_.isEqual(actual[k], expected[k]))
                 return console.log('FAILED: expected ' + JSON.stringify(expected) + ' but got ' + JSON.stringify(actual));
             }
      return console.log('passed');
    }


    let a = ['James', 'Paul']
    let e = [{'Name' : 'James', 'Age' : 10}, {'Name' : 'Paul', 'Age' : 10}]
    assertEquals(decorateClassListWithAges(a), e)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but I heard stringify only works if the object keys are in the same order, in this case they are, but I'd still like to know a comparison that didn't rely on stringify in the future. Thank you